# What is the srcData for ID2D1Bitmap::CreateBitmap

Tags: c++, bitmap, direct2d

I need to create a bitmap from an array of pixels for a raycaster I'm working on in Direct2D.  However, I'm having trouble understanding how to use the [CreateBitmap](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/d2d1/nf-d2d1-id2d1rendertarget-createbitmap(d2d1_size_u_constvoid_uint32_constd2d1_bitmap_properties__id2d1bitmap)) function.  Specifically, I'm not sure what the `srcData` parameter is supposed to be.  I'm pretty sure/hoping it's a pointer to an array of pixels, but I'm not sure how to set up that array.  What kind of array is it supposed to be?  What data type?  Etc.

Here's what I've tried:

```
    int width = 400, height = 400;
    D2D1::ColorF * arr = (D2D1::ColorF*)calloc(width * height * 4, sizeof(D2D1::ColorF));
    for (int i = 0; i < width * height * 4; i++) { arr[i] = D2D1::ColorF(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f); }
    // Create the bitmap and draw it on the screen
    ID2D1Bitmap * bmp;
    HRESULT hr;
    hr = renderTarget->CreateBitmap(
        D2D1::SizeU(width, height),
        arr,
        width * sizeof(int) * 4,
        D2D1::BitmapProperties(),
        &bmp);
    if (hr != S_OK) { return; } // I've tested and found that hr does not equal S_OK

    // Draw the bitmap...
```

What should the second and third lines look like?  Is there anything else I'm doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/d2d1/nf-d2d1-id2d1rendertarget-createbitmap(d2d1_size_u_constvoid_uint32_constd2d1_bitmap_properties__id2d1bitmap)):

```
HRESULT CreateBitmap(
  D2D1_SIZE_U                    size,
  const void                     *srcData,
  UINT32                         pitch,
  const D2D1_BITMAP_PROPERTIES & bitmapProperties,
  ID2D1Bitmap                    **bitmap
);
```

Your code:

```
hr = renderTarget->CreateBitmap(
    D2D1::SizeU(width, height),
    arr, // <<--- Wrong, see (a) below
    width * sizeof(int) * 4, // <<--- Close but wrong, see (b) below
    D2D1::BitmapProperties(), // <<--- Wrong, see (c) below
    &bmp);
```

(a) - you are supposed to provide an array of pixel data here, where the format depends on format of the bitmap. Note that this is optional an d you can create a bitmap without initialization. The pixels are not `D2D1::ColorF` exactly. They could be 4 byte RGBA data if you request respective bitmap format, see (c) below.

(b) - this is distance between rows in bytes, if your pixels are supposed to be 32-bit values you would normally want `Width * 4` here

(c) - this requests `DXGI_FORMAT_UNKNOWN` `D2D1_ALPHA_MODE_UNKNOWN` and results in bitmap creation error. You need a real format here such as `DXGI_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM` (see [Pixel Formats](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/using-color-in-direct2d#pixel-formats) and also [Supported Pixel Formats and Alpha Modes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct2d/supported-pixel-formats-and-alpha-modes))

The first link above shows how exactly bytes in memory map to pixel colors, and you are supposed to prepare your data respectively.

**UPD**

With `DXGI_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM` your initialization structure is this:

```
UINT8* Data = malloc(Height * Width * 4);
for(UINT Y = 0; Y < Height; Y++)
  for(UINT X = 0; X < Width; X++)
  {
    UINT8* PixelData = Data + ((Y * Width) + X) * 4;
    PixelData[0] = unsigned integer blue in range 0..255;
    PixelData[1] = unsigned integer red in range 0..255;
    PixelData[2] = unsigned integer green in range 0..255;
    PixelData[3] = 255;
  }
```

Comment: Okay, thanks.  So what should my `arr` look like if I used `DXGI_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM`?  Is it just an `int` or something?  Do I use hexadecimal or something to represent each color?  Could you include an example?  Thanks again.

Comment: Alright.  I think I almost got it.  First of all, I had to include `(UINT8*)` before the `malloc` since `malloc` returned a `void*`.  I also had to add `(cost void*)` before `Data` in `CreateBitmap` to get it to be the correct data type.  I'm not sure if I did that right.  Also, it says the fourth parameter, `DXGI_FORMAT_B8G8R8_UNORM`, is of the type `DXGI_FORMAT` instead of `const D2D1_BITMAP_PROPERTIES`.  Sorry that it's taking so long for me to get this :P  And thanks for all your help.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I figured it out now.  I needed 
```D2D1::BitmapProperties(
 D2D1::PixelFormat(
  DXGI_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM,
  D2D1_ALPHA_MODE_IGNORE
 )
),```
as my fourth parameter.  Thanks.